# How to query Windows DHCP server across multiple scopes for a hostname in Powershell

Tags: powershell, dhcp

I am trying to write a one liner that allows me to specify a hostname and then search across a list of scopeIDs for that DHCP lease. Powershell version:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14393  576
```

So far, I am using this:

```
Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName Server -ScopeId 172.17.16.0 | Where-Object HostName -match Hostname | FT ipaddress,hostname,clientid,addressstate
Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName Server -ScopeId 172.17.17.0 | Where-Object HostName -match Hostname | FT ipaddress,hostname,clientid,addressstate
Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName Server -ScopeId 172.17.18.0 | Where-Object HostName -match Hostname | FT ipaddress,hostname,clientid,addressstate
Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName Server -ScopeId 172.17.19.0 | Where-Object HostName -match Hostname | FT ipaddress,hostname,clientid,addressstate
Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName Server -ScopeId 172.17.76.0 | Where-Object HostName -match Hostname | FT ipaddress,hostname,clientid,addressstate
```

This works, but I have to change the hostname on each line using find/replace.

I was thinking of something like,

```
Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName Server -ScopeId 172.17.16.0,172.17.17.0,172.17.18.0,172.17.19.0,172.17.76.0 | Where-Object HostName -match Hostname | FT ipaddress,hostname,clientid,addressstate
```

but the array doesn't work under the ScopeId. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pipe in the IP addresses with a `foreach` or the alias `%` :

```
"172.17.16.0","172.17.17.0","172.17.18.0","172.17.19.0","172.17.76.0" | % {
    Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName Server -ScopeId $_ |
    Where-Object HostName -match Hostname |
    FT ipaddress,hostname,clientid,addressstate
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Awesome! Thanks so much.

Would there be any way to run

Comment: Would there be any way to run
Get-DhcpServerv4Scope and pipe that list of scope outputs as a variable to replace that array?

Comment: `(Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName Server).ScopeID | % { ...`

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thank you @BenH

Answer (score 0):

The following is not quite a one-liner, but for anyone who has many more scopes than is practical to manually identify:

```
$allscope = Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName "dhcpserver"

foreach ($ScopeID in $allscope) 
{Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName "dhcpserver" -ScopeId $ScopeID.scopeid | 
where {$_.hostname -match "hostname"}}
```